# Firestore query returning empty snapshot

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have a node websocket listener set to query some data from my database. Currently however the query returns an empty snapshot even though I know that the query should return something.

I'm making a simple node based forum (although I'm pretty new to Node so it's not that good lol) and I'm trying to query post data from the server to send back to the client. I've tried checking to see if my post references were correct and double checked that the values I'm querying exist within the collection. I've also already checked that the data was sent through the socket correctly so I'm at a loss.

```js
let query = db.collection('posts').where('id','==',postID);
query.get().then(snapshot => {
      if (snapshot.empty) {
        client.emit('resPost', 'Failed');
        return;
      }
      snapshot.forEach(doc => {
        console.log(doc.data());
        client.emit('resPost', doc.data());
      });
});
```

When I load the post page I get the response tied to the empty snapshot.

Edit: As suggested by @Phil I've included a log for the `postID` variable.

```js
console.log('postID', typeof postID, JSON.stringify(postID))
```

Output:

```
postID string "0"
```

Here's a screenshot of the console if needed. The ClientID is the ID of the websocket connection.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/9AwLX.jpg

Comment: So you get back the _"Failed"_ message? Have you tried debugging the value of `postID`?

Comment: @Phil Could you elaborate on that? Sorry I'm pretty new so I don't know what you mean by debugging the value. If you mean logging in the console to check that it's the correct value I've already done that.

Comment: _"If you mean logging in the console"_  something like that, yes (though an actual debugger is preferable). You should check that the value of `postID` is **exactly** what you expect. In particular, check for leading / trailing whitespace. You didn't answer my first question though. Also, what does your collection data look like? Does it even have an `id` property?

Comment: @Phil Ah sorry yes I receive the Failed response in my client when I try to request the post. The ````postID```` is an integer passed through the function so it shouldn't have any leading or trailing whitespace or other characters. The collection contains separate documents for each post. Each post has the data required for the forum including the ````id```` property.

Comment: Can you please add `console.log('postID', typeof postID, JSON.stringify(postID))` before your query and [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/58634722/edit) to include the output **exactly** as it appears in your console / terminal (screenshot if possible). Also, what happens if you omit the `.where()`? Do you get any results then?

Comment: @Phil I've edited the post above hopefully that helps. The console output is only one line so I just included it there since it's more convenient that way but if you still need a screenshot let me know. Omitting the query returned the full collection as expected.
````{ desc: 'Test Post.',
  content: 'Test Post.',
  date: '31th October 2019',
  id: 2,
  title: 'Test Post',
  author: 'Test' }
````
The client also received the data as expected.
https://imgur.com/a/5glY17m

Comment: Also this post is only one of the posts in the collection. I only included one document as the others are quite long and such have a really long output.

Comment: Humour me and try `.where('id', '==', parseInt(postID, 10))`

Comment: @Phil That seemed to have worked! If it's not too much trouble could you explain to me what that exactly did? Thanks a lot for your time.

Comment: Seems the Firestore query is type-sensitive so conditions on integer values should be made using integers instead of strings

Comment: I probably should have realised earlier that the URL query was a string and not an integer oop.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm quite surprised there isn't a duplicate question anywhere but here's your answer...

Firestore's query equality conditionals are type-sensitive. If your collection property is an integer, you need to compare it to an integer instead of a string.

For example

```js
db.collection('posts').where('id', '==', parseInt(postID, 10))
```

Comment: @Rayinator not a problem. I'm actually surprised by this since the docs have examples of using strings in `">"` and `"<"` comparisons ~ https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries#query_limitations